# Create array in function and use it another function

Tags: powershell

I have a program which gets VM information for a given user. It uses a menu system and the function `REFRESH_LIST` creates an array, creates an object containing VM information (ip address, name, etc.) and puts it into the array so the array is an array of objects which is as big as the amount of VMs the user has.

I then use this array to populate a table to display all the information to screen. I have another function `START_INSTANCE` which will start the VM based on the name of the VM but in an effort to check and make sure the user is only starting VMs assigned to them I want to go back into the array and check the VM name they entered exists in the array.

The issue I have is the array was built in one function and I need it in another. In reading I found it is a scope issue `$script:var` I built simple test functions and got a variable to be usable in another function when I apply that same `$script:var` to the array it is still not usable anywhere else.

Is there anything special with arrays or is there more to it than just scope ?

```
FUNCTION GET_HELP {
    ECHO ""
    ECHO " refresh  : REFRESH VM LIST" 
    ECHO " start    : START INSTANCE    : start <instance-id>"
    ECHO " stop     : STOP INSTANCE     : stop <instance-id>"
    ECHO " q        : QUIT"
    ECHO ""
}

FUNCTION INSTANCE_START {

    $i=0
    $CHECK=""
    $a.Length
    While ($i -le $a.Length) { 
    echo $CHECK
        If ($a[$i].INSTANCEID -contains $INSTANCEID) {
            $CHECK = "TRUE"}
        $i = $i+1
    Echo $CHECK
    }
    echo $CHECK
    IF ($CHECK = "TRUE") {
        #Start-EC2Instance -InstanceId 
        "STARTING " + $INSTANCEID
        ECHO $CHECK}
    ELSE {
    $CHECK=""
    "NO"}
    $INSTANCEID = ""
}

FUNCTION INSTANCE_STOP {
    #Stop-EC2Instance -InstanceId 
}
FUNCTION REFRESH_LIST {
Clear-Host
" LOADING VM LIST FOR "+$USERNAME
$date = get-date -format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
$Global:a = @()
(Get-EC2Instance).instances | ? {$_.Tags.Key -eq "NAME" -and $_.Tags.Value -eq $TEST_USER} | ForEach-Object {
        $instobj = New-Object System.Object
        $instobj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name STATE -value $_.state.name
        $instobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name INSTANCEID -value $_.InstanceID
        $instobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name IPADDRESS -value $_.PublicIPAddress
        IF ($_.state.name -eq 'running'){
            $time=New-TimeSpan -Start $_.LaunchTime -End $date
            $val="{0}d {1}h {2}m" -f $time.Days, $time.Hours, $time.Minutes
            $instobj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name TIME -value $val}
        else{$instobj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name TIME -value ""}
        $a += $instobj}
For ($i=0; $i -le $a.Length-1; $i++){
    $instanceTags = Get-EC2Tag -Filter @{ Name="resource-id"; Values=$a[$i].INSTANCEID } 
    $a[$i] | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name PROJECT -value $instanceTags.Where({$_.Key -eq "Project"}).Value
    $a[$i] | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name NAME -value $instanceTags.Where({$_.Key -eq "Name"}).Value
    $a[$i] | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name SOFTWARE -value $instanceTags.Where({$_.Key -eq "Oracle SW"}).Value
}
Clear-Host
echo $date
$a | sort STATE, PROJECT, NAME |Format-Table STATE, INSTANCEID, IPADDRESS, PROJECT, NAME, SOFTWARE, TIME -AutoSize
}

#REGION MAIN

REFRESH_LIST
DO {
$SELECTION = Read-Host ">"
$COMMAND,$INSTANCEID = $SELECTION.split(' ',2)
    SWITCH ($COMMAND) {
        '-h' {GET_HELP}
        'refresh' {REFRESH_LIST}
        'start' {INSTANCE_START}
        'stop' {'STOPPING INTANCE'}
        'q' {BREAK}
        DEFAULT {'ENTER -h FOR HELP'}
     }}
 until ($COMMAND -eq 'q')

 #ENDREGION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to resolve this would be to assign the array in the `$Global:` scope:

`$Global:arr`

Some example code:

```
function one {
    $Global:arr = @(1, 2, 3)
}

function two {
    one
    $arr
}

two
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

See [ss64](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-scopes.html) or run `help about_Scopes` for more details.

---

In the code that you posted, you could try:

`$Global:a = @()` in `REFRESH_LIST`

This small example is more reflective of your code:

```
function one {
    $Global:a = @(1,2,3)
}

function two {
    echo $a.Length
}

one
two
```

Where the output is `3`

---

As mentioned in the comments, this also works with `$Script`, and is preferable in your case. However, to ensure you are calling the same instance of the array each time, every time you use if you need to prefix it with whichever scope you decided to declare it into (`$Global:` or `$Script:`)

Comment: I don't want to call `function one` in `function two`. When I start the program it runs `REFRESH_LIST` which is where the array is built. Since that function takes some time to complete I really only want to run it once unless I specificity say run it again. I then have a `switch` menu which if I type in `start <host name>` I want it to take the `<host name>` I entered look into the array and come back with yes or no. Its an effort to check for miss types.

Comment: @themackyo Did you try declaring the array with `$Global:` in`REFRESH_LIST`? You really should post some code as without it is much more difficult to help.

Comment: I posted some code and have tried setting the array to `$Global` the array seems empty.

Comment: @themackyo I see that you put the `$Global:` in front of the function name rather than the array declaration - did you try putting the actual array in the global scope, like in my updated answer?

Comment: Yes, I tried both ways `global:refresh_list` and `$global:a`. The array seems empty both ways.

Comment: @themackyo Okay another thing I would try is replace all instances of `$a` with `$Global:a` - this way the shell will know you are targeting the global `$a` rather than declaring a new, scripted-scope `$a`

Comment: Ah, That did it. I didn't know you have to reference the `$Global:a` at all times. That is interesting, I figured if the var is declared as Global in the function all instances where it is referenced in the function at least should be global. I had to change EVERY instance of `$a` to `$Global:a`

Comment: I switch it to use `script` instead of `global` and it is still working  as intended, I believe `script` is more what I want.

Comment: @themackyo Cool, glad I could help! Yeah that makes a lot more sense, but the same principle - `PowerShell` allows you to declare variables in inner scopes with the same name as one in an outer scope, which requires us to be explicit when calling them